# Design a "Customer Account Profile" using Domain Driven Design

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, e-commerce, cqrs, software-design

I'm looking to create a micro-service following the Domain Driven Design, which will be responsible to handle the Customer Account Information in a e-commerce context.
For example : a customer has a list of delivery addresses, a list of billing address, a list of previous orders, cards etc etc.

Currently, I'm a the stage when I want to defined my aggregate/aggregates that will be involved.

[image]

As presented in this picture, Customer Account is the root object in my Customer Account Micro service. I'm not sure that I'm on the right track with this approach. Any guidance will be much appreciated, my goal is to define a Domain Driven Design approach for the Customer Account information, which basically needs to be able to store address,orders and maybe a lot of other customer related items. Is this the correct way to have a CustomerAccount aggregate model which will hold everything that I require?

Answer (score 0):

Your subdomains are often best served by representing certain areas of your business or organization (from a behavior perspective). I see you have a checkout service, which makes sense.

I think customer service is a choice which is dependant on your situation. A customer account micro-service does make sense, but I guess the question is should you have your order entity information in the customer service.

I would at least have a customer aggregate root and a separate order aggregate root. (Given they can both evolve and change independently). A step further would be to then separate a new service for Orders. Given customer account and orders have some clear responsibilities, independent of each other. Separating services can be tricky to know when and why.

Another reason beyond functionality is security and access patterns. Do you want to isolate customer information from orders (does customer information demand higher security boundaries ?). Are orders and customer profiles accessed the same( is the profile info a busier service so needs more resource ?). As always, I think its a balance between flexibility, control, and complexity.

So I am not sure there is a right or wrong. I hope that helps.